# How to use asyncio for asynchronous handler?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have a function which constantly yields some objects, say 1 per second and a handler which works 2 seconds and handles this objects. For example:

```
from time import sleep
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

def generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
        sleep(1)

def handler(number):
    sleep(2)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(str(number) + ' is even')
    else:
        print(str(number) + ' is odd')


for number in generator():
    handler(number)
```

So, for example '2 is even' is printed 6 seconds after the program starts. How do I reduce this time to 4 seconds ( 2 seconds for generator + 2 seconds for handler) using asyncio? I need to set up asynchronous handling of the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need couple of changes here:

1. your `generator` currently is a "generator", change it to ["asynchronous generator"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/) so that you can use `async for`. This way it can give the control back to eventloop.
2. Use async version of `sleep` in `asyncio` library: `asyncio.sleep`. `time.sleep` doesn't cooperate with other tasks.
3. Change your `handler` sync function to a "coroutine".

```py
import asyncio


async def generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def handler(number):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(str(number) + " is even")
    else:
        print(str(number) + " is odd")


async def main():
    async for number in generator():
        asyncio.create_task(handler(number))


asyncio.run(main())
```

Now, your first task is `main`, `asyncio.run()` automatically creates it as Task. Then when this task is running, it iterates asynchronously through the `generator()`. The values are received then for each number, you create a new Task out of `handler` coroutine.

This way the sleep times are overlapped. When it waits for new number for 1 second, it also actually waits for `handler()` one second. Then when the number is received, one second of `handler()` task is already passed, it only needs 1 second.

You can see the number of tasks if you want:

```py
async def main():
    async for number in generator():
        print(f"Number of all tasks: {len(asyncio.all_tasks())}")
        asyncio.create_task(handler(number))
```

Because each handler sleeps `2` seconds, and your number generator sleeps `1` seconds, You see that in every iteration `2` Tasks are exist in event loop. Change `await asyncio.sleep(1)` to `await asyncio.sleep(0.5)` in `generator` coroutine, you will see that `4` tasks are in event loop in every iteration.

---

#### Answer to the comment:

> Can I do the same thing if I use API which doesn't let me create
> asynchronous generator, but just a normal one? Can I still
> asynchronously handle yielded objects?

Yes you can. Just note that if you don't have asynchronous generator, you can't use `async for`, which means your iteration is synchronous. **But**, you have to do a little trick for it to work. When your `main()` task is being executed, it constantly get a value from `generator` generator and creates a Task for it, but it doesn't give a chance to other tasks to run. You need `await asyncio.sleep(0)`:

```py
import asyncio
import time


def generator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)


async def handler(number):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(str(number) + " is even")
    else:
        print(str(number) + " is odd")


async def main():
    for number in generator():
        print(f"Number of all tasks: {len(asyncio.all_tasks())}")
        asyncio.create_task(handler(number))
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


asyncio.run(main())
```